# Showing something does not have a solution on an open interval (is my idea correct?)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

I saw a question that asks whether sinx=x has a solution on (0,pi/2). I know that it does not, since 0 is not contained in the interval, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Do I suppose it does, then find a contradiction? 
I was thinking that if I suppose it does, that would mean that I'd set g(x) = sinx - x, and I'd note that for some c in (0, pi/2), g(c) = 0 = sin(c) - c, since I'm supposing it does have a solution. Do I just say from here that the only point that satisfies this is c = 0, but 0 is not in the interval, which is a contradiction?

Comment: Maybe show $x-\sin x$ is increasing in our interval.

Comment: Andre is correct, show that x-sinx is increasing over the interval and then show the initial value is greater than 0 so it cannot ever be 0 on the interval.

Comment: Since it's open, I don't know what the initial value is, do I? If I know it's increasing from 0 to pi/2, and x - sinx = 0 at x = 0, which is open in the interval, I know it can't be 0. Is that the idea?

Comment: @user269711: Yes if you show it is **strictly** increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make the prove rigorous here. We are going to make use of Rolle's theorem in our prove.

First, let $g(x) = sin(x) - x$, and consider $g(x)$ defined on $[0,pi/2)$.
We do know that $g(0) = 0$. Now suppose to the contrary, there exist some $t \in (0,\pi/2)$ such that $g(t) = 0$ . Then by Rolle's Theorem, there exist $c\in (0,t)$ such that $g'(c) = 0$.

but $g'(c) = cos(c) = 0$ for $c\in (0,pi/2)$ is a contradiction.

therefore $g(x)$ has no solution in $(0,pi/2)$